# jQuery - val not refresing data from input / UI slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using some code from here (stackoverflow) i've created my own one. Presented below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#slider-1').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    change: function(e, ui) {
      $('#input-1').val(ui.value);     
    }
  });

});

$('input').change(function(){
        var value1=$('input[name="input-1"]').val();
        var number1=0.01;

        var Total1=(value1*number1).toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
        $('input[name="input-2"]').val(Total1);
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider" id="slider-1"></div>
<input class="input-1" id="input-1" name="input-1" /><br />
<input class="input-2" id="input-2" name="input-2" />
```

CSS:

```
input {
  margin:10px auto;
  clear:both;
  width:80%;
}

.slider {
  margin:1em;
  width:90%;
}
```

The thing is that - slider works and present the value in the first input. But unfortuntalley my multiply function doesn't work. Why? How to make / create instant supervision input-1 by input-2?

jsfiddle shows whats going on - https://jsfiddle.net/c23wuemw/1/

Comment: You're not triggering a `change` event after setting a new value for `#input-1`. That's probably the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#slider-1').slider({
     min: 0,
     max: 100,
     change: function(e, ui) {
       $('#input-1').val(ui.value);
        var value1=parseInt($('input[name="input-1"]').val());

        var number1=0.01;

        var Total1=(value1*number1).toString().replace(/\./g, ',');
        $('input[name="input-2"]').val(Total1);
    }
 });

});
```

I've moved your .change code to the correct event in the .slider inititation, and a I did a parseInt on the value prior to multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

$('#input-1').val(ui.value).trigger('change');

Trigger the change event on input manually after the val is updated.